# Test a character for being a valid Julia one-character variable name?

Tags: julia

How to test whether a single Unicode character is a valid variable name. The manual says:

> Variable names must begin with a letter (A-Z or a-z), underscore, or a subset of Unicode code points greater than 00A0; in particular, Unicode character categories Lu/Ll/Lt/Lm/Lo/Nl (letters), Sc/So (currency and other symbols), and a few other letter-like characters (e.g. a subset of the Sm math symbols) are allowed.

Is there a function which tests a character to see if it's a valid variable name? `isvalid()` looks like it checks to see whether a character is a valid character, which might not be the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Base.isidentifier` for that:

```
julia> Base.isidentifier("a")
true

julia> Base.isidentifier("a′")
true

julia> Base.isidentifier("1a′")
false

julia> Base.isidentifier("â")
true
```

Comment: Cool thanks - any idea why it's undocumented/exported?

Comment: It was/is considered a helper and not a public facing/exposed function. I will try to throw together a PR to update this.